# How use static resources in xaml?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I would like take out my StringFormat to static resources.

I tried to do it but it does not work

```
.. xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
    ResourceDictionary>
           <system:String x:Key="MyFormat">'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/{0}?d=mm&amp;s=150'</system:String>
        </ResourceDictionary>
```

Here I initializes mine StringFormat

```
 <Image.Source>
           <UriImageSource Uri="{Binding EmailHash,StringFormat={StaticResource MyFormat}}}" />
</Image.Source>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have single quotes in your `StaticResouce`

```
<system:String x:Key="MyFormat">http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/{0}?d=mm&amp;s=150</system:String>
```